# copy random multiple excel cells into a single row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a bit new to VBA so I have a question. I have 2 sheets in excel. First has a table that serves a purpose of a "form" for users to enter data. I need a way to copy random cells from the first sheet into a (first empty)single row on the second sheet and do so for every new entry.

For example I need to copy data from sheet1, cells:J4,B5,J5,K6,D8,E11 to sheet2, cells: A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2. On the next entry in sheet1 and I need the data to go on sheet2, cells: A3,B3,C3,D3,E3,F3, on the next one to A4,B4,C4,D4,E4,F4 and so on.

Thanks in advance to anyone and everyone who can help.

Comment: Do you truly mean 'random'? Do the particular cells in sheet1 need to correspond to any particular columns in sheet2? I think we need a bit more info here. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Joshua Hysong: 'Random access' is read that as.

Comment: You could start by recording a macro.  Then clean it up by eliminating all the "Selects" and "Activates" you will see there.  Plenty of examples in this forum about that.  You should also consider developing a user form to enter your selections of cells to copy.  Post back with your code if you run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

not a very elegant solution, but it works. If you don't have a header row on sheet 2 remove the +1 after iRow

```
Sub CopyCells()

Dim iRow As Integer

'Get last row on sheet 2
iRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'copy each cell on sheet 2
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow + 1, 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J4")
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow + 1, 2) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow + 1, 3) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J5")
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow + 1, 4) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K6")
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow + 1, 5) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D8")
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow + 1, 6) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E11")

End Sub
```

Comment: Guys thank you all for a quick response. El dude did exactly what I needed, simple yet effective! I will try out the other two soon, I'm rushing with the first one 'cause it's working and I'm on a deadline. Thank you once more, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to enter data into another sheet when data is entered into sheet1 then I suggest looking into using the worksheet_change event.

Here is a quick example I put together:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C5")
    Set Sheet2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        lastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        ' Start on second row
        If lastRow = 1 Then lastRow = 2

        lastColumn = Sheet2.Cells(lastRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        ' Move to next row after the 5th column
        If lastColumn > 5 Then
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
            lastColumn = 1
        End If

        Sheet2.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn + 1).Value = Target.Value

    End If

End Sub
```

This function will write whatever values are entered into cells A1 through C5 on Sheet1 to Sheet 2. The values will be written starting on Row 2 and after the 5th column new values will automatically be written to the next row.

You'll need to adapt this example to your specific situation but hopefully it helps you get started in the right direction.

If you are wanting to wait until all data is entered into sheet1 first you can easily add a button that triggers a similar macro to copy the data dynamically to the correct row/columns like above.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
    'It seems, you want to linearize your range.
    'Use following code to achieve that.
    'Plz customize as per your exact needs
    Sub LinearizeMyRange()
        'find last row in sheet2
        Sheet2.Activate
        sheet2lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'Linearize range to next row
        n = 1
        For Each c In Sheet1.Range("A1:C5")
        Sheet2.Cells(sheet2lastrow + 1, n) = c
        n = n + 1
        Next c
    End Sub
```